# Am I correct? If not, why?

Tags: sentence-construction

If we look at the sentence:

> He was the person responsible for the incident.

In this sentence, something is omitted. The complete sentence is:

> He was the person who was responsible for the incident.

So to omit a part before an adjective we just omit the relative pronoun and the verb.

---

Another example of what I mean:

> He is a person daring to challenge him.

Here the complete sentence is:

> He is a person who dares to challenge him.

So here, to omit, we omit "who" and we change "dares" to "daring" i.e a participle. This is because it is before a verb.

**Am I correct? If not, why?**

Answer (score 0):

This kind of construction is called ellipsis, which means to drop some words that will be understood even though omitted. When ellipsis is allowed and what words can be omitted probably cannot be reduced to any simple set of rules. One common type of ellipsis is

> noun + relative pronoun + form of "be" + adjective

gets shortened to

> noun + adjective

If you are uncertain about using ellipsis, do not use it. It is never an error in grammar to avoid ellipsis.

**EDIT in response to a question by the OP**

Both sentences in your question are examples of the kind of ellipsis mentioned above

> person who was responsible

"Person" is a noun; "who" is a relative pronoun; "was" is a form of the verb "be," and "responsible" is an adjective. It gets shortened by ellipsis through eliminating the pronoun and verb to

> person responsible

If you are unsure whether ellipsis is permitted, just don't use it. It is never required.

Comment: Sir please drop an example so I can understand it well.

Comment: I have added text to my answer using your original example.

Comment: Sir another question is regarding to a sentence : He is the man doing it. Is it, he is the man who does it or he is the man who is doing it. Which one is more appropriate or correct.